# Abstract class values are null after calling super

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have the following program:

```
public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal dog = new Dog("larry");
        dog.speak();
    }

}

public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;

    public Animal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void speak();
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

    private String name; // is this even needed?

    public Dog(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I am " + name);

    }
}
```

Running this program prints `I am null`, which is not what I want.

Why doesn't it just use the `Animal` variable defined `name` and print out `larry`?

What is the proper way to do this?

If I remove the `name` from the `Dog` class, is it possible to reference the `Animal` name variable while still keeping it `private`?

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` variable used in

```
System.out.println("I am " + name);
```

is the one defined in the `Dog` class. It is never set, hence `null` is printed.

There is no need to define `name` in both `Animal` and `Dog`. My suggestion would be to:

- remove `name` from `Dog`
- change the visibility of `name` in `Animal` to `protected`

If you want to keep the access to `name` as `private`, add a "getter" method for `name` to `Animal`, thus:

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
public class Dog {
    @Override
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println("I am " + getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but if I was to remove it, and wanted to refer to the `Animal` name variable, how do I do this? I call super, so it should initialize it on the Animal level

Comment: @KSplitX I've updated my answer to reflect all parts of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variable `name` in `Dog`; it is a separate variable from the one in `Animal`.  The `Animal` constructor initializes the `name` in `Animal` correctly, but the `speak` method in `Dog` refers to the uninitialized `name` variable in `Dog`; the variable in `Dog` is the one that is in scope inside the `Dog` class code.  Delete the `name` variable in `Dog` to avoid confusion.

But to keep `name` private in `Animal` and access it in a subclass, provide a getter method in `Animal`.

```
public String getName() { return name; }  // or protected
```

Then you can call it in `Dog`:

```
System.out.println("I am " + getName());
```

Output:

```
I am larry
```